# Excel macro to update links from other spreadsheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that I can apply to my worksheets.

Scenario:
I have a workbook that is like a summary page. It has links to the hardcoded numbers from other workbooks. In many instances, the folders have been moved around or a sheet may be renamed/removed, etc. The links end up failing and it causes many #REF errors. THis happens because multiple people can manipulate the spreadsheets on the shared network drive.

I would like to solve this problem by creating a fail safe. Essentially, an "update" button that would save a copy of all the references that were updated into a new worksheet named "updated data" and add a timestamp to when the last update was performed. This data would change only if there is a change to the reference.
 For example, if on Monday, cell A1 references a workbook's cell A1 and returns the value $1234.56, it will store the refernce in a seperate worksheet. Now, on Tuesday I click update, and the the reference A1 workbook has been moved or deleted. I will still return the $1234.56 rather than the #REF. Finally, there is some kind of notification that the update failed, would be great, maybe highlight the cells.

Thanks for reading and providing your insight.

Comment: Yoou would be much better off putting in a structure around the how the file are managed.....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go down the validation path then I suggest you:

1. Use code such as below to validate if each of the links is intact. This code snippets indentfies where linked files do not reside in the same directory as the "Summary FIle"
2. You could add a follow-up section that updates the valid linked workbooks, and thaat skips the errors
3. If the sheet has been renamed but the link source is valid, Excel will prompt you to select a sheet to linkk to
4. This still leaves you exposed to people moving data within the feeder sheets, especially if rows and columns can be inserted or deleted.
5. *Preventing the issue is much better than a failsafe*. The best option is to use a single sheet on all your feeder workbooks to consolidate the data to be linked to the summary file, then import this sheet in full to the summary file. This means people can

   - rename/move/add sheets
   - add/delete columns/rows

without impacting the consolidated data sheet

**code to identify missing links**

'looks to identify where source files are not located in the same directory as the Summary File

```
    Dim vLinkArr()
    Dim lngLink As Long
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim strGoodMsg As String

    On Error Resume Next
    vLinkArr = ThisWorkbook.LinkSources
    On Error GoTo 0
    If IsEmpty(vLinkArr) Then Exit Sub
    For lngLink = 1 To UBound(vLinkArr)
            If Left$(vLinkArr(lngLink), InStrRev(vLinkArr(lngLink), "\") - 1) <> ThisWorkbook.Path Then
                If InStr(Left$(vLinkArr(lngLink), InStrRev(vLinkArr(lngLink), "\") - 1), ThisWorkbook.Path) = 0 Then
                    strMsg = strMsg & vLinkArr(lngLink) & vbCrLf
                Else
                    strGoodMsg = strGoodMsg & vLinkArr(lngLink) & Chr(10)
                End If
            Else
                strGoodMsg = strGoodMsg & vLinkArr(lngLink) & Chr(10)
            End If

    Next
    If strMsg <> vbNullString Then MsgBox strMsg
```